# Vimdiff - How to hide all same lines in both files and show only different ones

Tags: vim, vimdiff

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

besides differences shows also same lines from both files. Is it possible to hide them? How to do it?

Comment: Also answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352204:

You can do this once off by setting options on the vimdiff command: `vimdiff -c 'set diffopt=filler,context:0' file1 file2`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Vim is a text editor (not a specialized diff viewer), the full contents of both files are kept (so you can do edits and persist them). Vim usually just "hides" multiple identical lines by *folding them away*; they are still present, just not visible.

You can influence how many identical lines are kept around changes (default: 6 lines above and below) via the `context` value of the `'diffopt'` option. So, to completely fold all identical lines:

```
:set diffopt+=context:0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still showing common lines if common line is going in sequence with different. one after another

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by [Ingo Karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) worked perfectly in Linux. Thanks for sharing it. However, it's not working on Mac.